# Scroll con cxxdroid

Tags: android, c, scroll, text, texto

Tengo un programa en **cxxdroid** que muestra varias líneas de texto por la salida estándar pero como su longitud es mayor que el tamaño de la pantalla se muestra solamente el final.

Probé con la función *scroll* de **ncurses** pero al hacer scroll se muestran en blanco las primeras líneas.

Alguien sabe si es posible hacer scroll en la salida de un programa hecho con **cxxdroid**?

Gracias por anticipado.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Te propongo una alternativa. Usa [Termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-app)